# Арифметический парсер

Tags: c++, польская-запись

Всем добрый день!

Для написания лабораторной работы требуется арифметический парсер. Может у кого нибудь завалялся .cpp-шник? Достаточно, чтобы распознавались основные арифметические действия и пара функций ( sin, cos,log).

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдёт [обратная польская запись](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E1%F0%E0%F2%ED%E0%FF_%EF%EE%EB%FC%F1%EA%E0%FF_%E7%E0%EF%E8%F1%FC). В статье по ссылке есть пример реализации на C. Вот [на c++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/rpnexpressionevaluator.aspx). Простым гуглением нашёл ещё [реализацию](http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=1492), но не проверял.

Comment: Обратите внимание что тут логичнее всего использовать реализацию на стеках

Answer (score 1):

Еще стоит покопать в сторону генераторов кода парсера (типа [yacc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)).

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что Вам стоит с самого начала разбираться с обратной польской записью и теорией компиляторов (Если надо - погуглите Dragon Book).

Мне очень понравился подход вот в этой книге:

[Д. Креншоу. Давайте создадим компилятор](http://bookz.ru/authors/djek-kren6ou/davaite-_281.html)

Просто и доступно. Прочитав буквально 1-2 главы Вы уже напишите все что Вам надо и к тому же получите информацию для дальнейшего развития (буде таковое понадобится)...